# Camera issues on Acer Aspire Timeline

Tags: windows-7, drivers, skype, webcam, acer-aspire

I have strange issues with my webcam. In browser it works just fine (in Flash, for example). But when I go to Skype options it says I don't have any webcams. I can see webcam in device manager and it says it's working fine.

I tried to delete config.xml for Skype, as their site suggests, but got nothing.

Also, I have ManyCam Webcam Source in browser webcam selector, although I've deleted ManyCam long ago. Maybe this is related to Skype problem?

When I'm trying to install webcam driver from Acer site, it also says I don't have any webcams.

Notebook is Acer Aspire Timeline 5750G. OS is Windows 7 Home Basic Service Pack 1, 64 bit.

**UPD**: Okay, installing and uninstalling ManyCam removed it from webcam selector. Browser still uses "1.3 MP Webcam", Skype still cannot see it.

**UPD**: Connecting USB cam makes it available to browser without problems but Skype still cannot see any. I'm reinstalling Skype right now.

**UPD**: Nope, didn't help

**Device manager info**:

1.3M HD Webcam

Hardware ID:

USB\VID_064E&PID_C218&REV_0332&MI_00

USB\VID_064E&PID_C218&MI_00

**UPD AGAIN**

Okay, it seems I miss registry entries for some MediaTypes (whatever it is), one of them MJPG. That's probably why camera doesn't work. When we load Advanced Graph Manager for media, one of the prefered media types is written as {47504A4D-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71} (others have normal names like "YUV2"). Google says this guid belongs to MJPG. Is there any way to restore/reinstall these mediatypes?

Comment: What is your webcam?

Comment: It's built into the notebook.

Comment: What is it called in Device Manager (normally under "Sound, video and game controllers") and what is "Hardware Ids" in click-right/Properties/Details.

Comment: Updated post with hardware info.

Answer (score 2):

First step is to fully patch using Windows Update and including all optional updates.

Second step is to check that your drivers are at least as recent as those on the [Acer Drivers and Manuals page](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers).
(Or you can install first the drivers that seem to apply, at least the Chipset and the USB Drivers, then reboot and see if Windows Update can find more recent drivers.)

Third step is to ensure that your applications are up to date (same page on "Application"
tab), and especially try out the [Acer WebCam Application](http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Application/Camera/Camera_Acer_1.0.1216_W7x64_A.zip?acerid=634304174617888877&Step1=NOTEBOOK&Step2=ASPIRE&Step3=ASPIRE%205750G&OS=ALL&LC=en&BC=ACER&SC=EMEA_28).

If this still doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: Drives installer says he cannot find a webcam.

Comment: Which installer is that?

Comment: http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Application/Camera/Camera_Acer_1.0.1216_W7x64_A.zip

Comment: That's the installer for the Acer WebCam Application. Did you do all the other steps above?

Comment: I'll try when I get home to notebook

Comment: The Acer Webcam App is the only piece of software on their website relating to this laptop model that is for the camera. I assumed the drivers would be bundled with it, but it looks like they aren't.

Comment: The drivers are in the Drivers section, not bundled with anything else.

Comment: You could also try uninstalling Skype, cleaning up its folders, download the latest version, and reinstall.

Comment: I tried, it changes nothing.

Comment: (1) You say you have a problem with your registry. Have you run a registry cleaner? (2) If this problem is recent enough, you might rollback your Windows to a system restore point from before the problem. (3) You might also try uninstalling the latest Skype and installing instead version 6.1, if it works disable automatic updates (4) See this link using Internet explorer : [Automatically diagnose and fix Skype audio and webcam issues](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/skype/).

Comment: I don't have rollback point, sadly. I'll try exporting entries from another Win7 machine and importing them here.

Comment: Skype video-handling changed in 6.2, so there is a chance that 6.1 will work. See also my point 4.

Comment: Nothing helped.

Comment: Maybe I'll just reinstall Win7.

Comment: Reinstall or refresh? For reinstall - make sure to download first on external disk all the drivers. If refresh works (restore to initial state), then update drivers with attention.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing the Acer Camera software from their website?

[Link](http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Application/Camera/Camera_Acer_1.0.1216_W7x64_A.zip)

Comment: Yes. It says I don't have a webcam :(